# spring-data-mongo @Query doesn't work when requesting with a date

Tags: java, mongodb-query, spring-data

I'm trying to use @Query with a @MongoRepository this way :

```
public interface VisasRepository extends MongoRepository<DomainVisa, Long> {

    @Query("{'codeReseau': '?0' , 'debutEffet': { $lte: '?3' } , 'garantie.codeProduit': '?1' , 'garantie.codeCouverture': '?2'}")
    List<DomainVisa> filterVisas(String codeReseau, String codeProduit, String codeCouverture, Date date);
}
```

When I call the `filterVisas` I get this error :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1584112318752,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "JSON reader was expecting ':' but found ' : '.",
    "path": "/visas"
}
```

FYI when I remove `'debutEffet': { $lte: '?3' }` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your date in a format that mongoDB can understand:

you can try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
String dateForMongo = sdf.format(debutEffet);
```